# Nodejs (Infinispan) : Does Infinispan put method returns null for key inserted in cache for first time?

Tags: node.js, infinispan, infinispan-9

I have been reviewing the infinispan documentation and overloaded put method returns the value being replaced, or null if nothing is being replaced.

I am using overloaded put method with nodejs and it's not returning expected data, getting undefined.

how can I achieve this with nodejs?

Looked at the documentation, need assistance to understand the behavior with Nodejs

Documentation Link : https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.2/apidocs/org/infinispan/commons/api/BasicCache.html#put-K-V-

```
V put(K key,
  V value,
  long lifespan,
  TimeUnit unit)
```

An overloaded form of `put(Object, Object)`, which takes in lifespan parameters.

Parameters:

- key - key to use
- value - value to store
- lifespan - lifespan of the entry. Negative values are interpreted as unlimited lifespan.
- unit - unit of measurement for the lifespan

Returns:

- the value being replaced, or null if nothing is being replaced.

Looked at the documentation, need assistance to understand the behavior with Nodejs

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/infinispan/js-client/blob/main/lib/infinispan.js#L327 it looks like `put`'s third argument `opts` can have property `previous` that makes it return the old value, so try:

```
const oldValue = client.put('key', 'value', { previous: true })
```